# Setting custom layers to culling mask by script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, layer

I want to create layers through my script and set it as a culling mask during run time. I'm having the following code that creates new layers.

```
public class LayerMaskEx
{
    public static void CreateLayer(string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("name", "New layer name string is either null or empty.");

        var tagManager = new SerializedObject(AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("ProjectSettings/TagManager.asset")[0]);
        var layerProps = tagManager.FindProperty("layers");
        var propCount  = layerProps.arraySize;

        SerializedProperty firstEmptyProp = null;

        for (var i = 0; i < propCount; i++)
        {
            var layerProp = layerProps.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);

            var stringValue = layerProp.stringValue;

            if (stringValue == name) return;

            if (i < 8 || stringValue != string.Empty) continue;

            if (firstEmptyProp == null)
                firstEmptyProp = layerProp;
        }

        if (firstEmptyProp == null)
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("Maximum limit of " + propCount + " layers exceeded. Layer \"" + name + "\" not created.");
            return;
        }

        firstEmptyProp.stringValue = name;
        tagManager.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

I'm creating a new layer and set it as a culling mask  as follows,

```
LayerMaskEx.CreateLayer("Red");
FirstPersonCamera.cullingMask = 1<<8;
```

I want to have only the first 7 layers to be selected for the culling mask. Unfortunately, its not working as expected.  Is there any way to do so with the custom layers?

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve by creating layer at runtime ? I can't think of a reason to do so, instead of creating some in your project, get them with a serialized field and work with that.

Comment: it is just to prevent the end-user from creating it.

Comment: Layers are created in the editor only, how would an end user create layer, and why ?

Comment: it is going to be a unity package hence the layer creation is required